# Tensorflow- Recurrent Neural Networks

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I got the files reader.py and ptb_word_lm.py from google and tried running them as `python ptb_word_lm.py --data_path=/tmp/simple-examples/data/ --model small`. Please help me in resolving these errors.

Errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ptb_word_lm.py", line 321, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 43, in run
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "ptb_word_lm.py", line 268, in main
    raw_data = reader.ptb_raw_data(FLAGS.data_path)
  File "/home/ymakkapa/TensorFlow/reader.py", line 51, in ptb_raw_data
    word_to_id = _build_vocab(train_path)
  File "/home/ymakkapa/TensorFlow/reader.py", line 17, in _build_vocab
    data = _read_words(filename)
  File "/home/ymakkapa/TensorFlow/reader.py", line 13, in _read_words
    return f.read().decode("utf-8").replace("\n", "<eos>").split()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 106, in read
    self._preread_check()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 73, in _preread_check
    compat.as_bytes(self.__name), 1024 * 512, status)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 24, in __exit__
    self.gen.next()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 469, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: /tmp/simple-examples/data/ptb.train.txt
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you must download and extract the data in the same directory with you python code

`$ wget http://www.fit.vutbr.cz/~imikolov/rnnlm/simple-examples.tgz`

`$ tar xvf simple-examples.tgz`

Then, you must specify the data directory path for the code to work.
You can read the documentation that give sample command to run the program

`$ python ptb_word_lm.py --data_path=simple-examples/data/`

Comment: Have you run these commands too to download and extract the data?

`$ wget http://www.fit.vutbr.cz/~imikolov/rnnlm/simple-examples.tgz

$ tar xvf simple-examples.tgz`

Comment: First, I ran reader.py and then ptb_word_lm.py. I downloaded that zip but did not extract it. can u just tell me how to do it?

Comment: i've edited my post, u can download and extract the data by executin that command in your terminal

Comment: Thanks a lot Arianto. Both of ur commands worked. but there are many errors on running "python ptb_word_lm.py --data_path=/tmp/simple-examples/data/ --model small" after executing commands given by you. can you please help me

Comment: I did as you said and getting some errors. i am not able to post the errors as the number of characters is too long

Answer (score 0):

Using the complete path should solve your problem. 
Use

`python models/tutorials/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py --data_path=simple-examples/data/ --model=small`